# Multiple height box all on top

Tags: css, grid, flexbox

I know this isn't possible with css 2, but now with Flexbox...

This trick on the picture can be achieved with CSS only?

[http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/430383flexbox.jpg http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/430383flexbox.jpg](http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/430383flexbox.jpg)

The **HTML** :

```
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: Why not use css3? and use a javascript fallback?

Comment: My panel require latest browser, and I want minimised the JS. That's why I want use only the CSS if this is possible.

Comment: latest browser? then you can use css3, or I am getting it wrong?

Comment: Yes, actually I want use only CSS3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what developers wanted to achieve isn't still possible i'm afraid.

the masonry layout, with "floating" boxes but with reading from left to right isn't possible yet, even with flexbox

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/g8Ky9/

in the example you can see the alternatives you have; the third one looks promising but the box order is probably not what you want to get (top to bottom instead left to right)

sure you can switch boxes easily using css-flexbox's property `order` but you will need javascript for it, and calculating the correct offset isn't easy

that's really sad to say admit, but this goal isn't possible to achieve even with CSS3

```
.container
    {padding:10px;border:1px red solid;width:960px;display:flex;flex-wrap:wrap;flex-direction:row;align-items:flex-start;}

.container > div
    {padding:10px;width:200px;margin:10px;background:red;font-size:20px;text-align:center;font-weight:bold;font-family:sans-serif;}

.container.t1
    {align-items:stretch;}

.container.t2
    {flex-direction:column;height:180px;}

.container > div:nth-child(1){min-height:20px}
.container > div:nth-child(2){min-height:40px}
.container > div:nth-child(3){min-height:60px}
.container > div:nth-child(4){min-height:40px}
.container > div:nth-child(5){min-height:20px}
.container > div:nth-child(6){min-height:60px}
.container > div:nth-child(7){min-height:40px}
.container > div:nth-child(8){min-height:20px}


that's the base:
<div class="container">
    <div>1</div><div>2</div><div>3</div><div>4</div>
    <div>5</div><div>6</div><div>7</div><div>8</div>
</div>

you can fill the empty space:
<div class="container t1">
    <div>1</div><div>2</div><div>3</div><div>4</div>
    <div>5</div><div>6</div><div>7</div><div>8</div>
</div>

or do the masonry layout like this, but with order of boxes wrong:
<div class="container t2">
    <div>1</div><div>2</div><div>3</div><div>4</div>
    <div>5</div><div>6</div><div>7</div><div>8</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this tehnique in my website for display some post. This will change very much your code but I know that works. I display all post in an ordered list (like container) and listed items (li) for every single post.

CSS:

```
#container  {
clear:both;
-moz-column-count:3;
-moz-column-gap:20px;
-webkit-column-count:3;
-webkit-column-gap:20px;
width:70%;
position:relative;
margin:20px auto }

#post {
width:100%;
display:inline-block;
list-style:none;
margin-bottom:40px }
```

HTML

```
<ol id="container">
 <li id="post">..</li>
 <li id="post">..</li>
 <li id="post">..</li>
 <li id="post">..</li>
 ...
</ol>
```

For an example, visit [this page](http://ideage.ro/timp-liber/) from my website. Sorry for my english. If you have any questions please ask me.

Comment: I know about this technique, but my box have some effect (like box-shadow) and column-count cut column and effect : http://jsfiddle.net/jerjako/6tYG9/